# Laravel: Highchart column with filter by year and classroom

Tags: laravel, highcharts, laravel-8

I want to create highcharts that are the student's total with year and classroom dropdown filters. This is the graph that I want:

[image: want]

the classrooms table has a relationship with the students table:

[image: table]

This is the classrooms table:

[image: table]

This is the student table:

[image: table]

This is the code :

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Jumlah Siswa'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'siswa'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f} siswa</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: "Jumlah Siswa",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mholt/PapaParse/master/papaparse.js"></script>
<select class="year">
  <option value=''>Year</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<select class="class">
  <option value=''>Class</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>

</select>
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
```

How to code dropdown filter with class and year parameters? Thank you

Comment: Hi @php, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: okay, I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

You can add `change` event listener and update series data by `setData` method:

```
const data = {
    general: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    2018: [9, 3, 5],
    2019: [1, 3, 2],
    2020: [2, 1, 5]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
});

document.getElementById('year').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.value) {
        chart.series[0].setData(data[e.target.value]);
    } else {
        chart.series[0].setData(data.general);
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sjrv57z4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData